# Failing to add tableview to uiview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I'm dynamically creating uiviews which contain uitableviews (uiviews are tableview and datasource delegates for their respective tables. The uiviews are created using a xib file).  When I reach the numberOfRowsInSection function and try to return [self.mydata count], mydata is empty.

1. When I break at the numberOfRowsInSection function I've noticed each uiview does not have the same address as any of the uiviews I previously created.
2. I've noticed my numberOfRowsInSection function is called after all the views are created and added to my viewcontroller.

   3. numberOfRowsInSection is called multiple times, but is not equal to the number of uiviews I have created.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.  **I was setting the uitableviewdelegate and uitableviewdatasource to the uiview in the xib file, when in fact I want the File's Owner (which is the specific uiview created at runtime).**

I simply clicked and dragged (in the xib file) from the delegate and datasource outlets to the File's Owner placeholder button thing.